# Single Login Between Opencart and custom website

Tags: php, database, authentication, opencart

So I'm developing a website for a school project, we are creating a website that has a user database for access on certain pages as well as a online store.
I have done so research into Opencart but am unable to find out if I'm able to extend the login banner on opencart to my custom webpages.

So my questions are:

1. Is this possible?(I'd like to not have to create 2 user dbs)
2. If so, where would I look to find the code needed to do this?(online or in the opencart files)

I know that there is supposed to be code here but I have yet to find the code.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well you could use the same user credentials in opencart and the other site. You should look into how to access a database using PHP & MySQL.

Comment: Have a look at some od the solutions here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047596/cross-domain-authentication