# Two domains, one site, one SSL checkout. How to get cookies?

Tags: php, javascript, ssl, cookies, multiple-domains

There is a multilingual web shop, visitors can access from two domains, with different language:
**hxxp://x.com** - English
**hxxp://x.ru** - Russian, which is an add-on domain to x.com.

The authentication and cart pages are here, through SSL:
**https**://x.com/index.php?mode=login

How can I use the cookie informations of x.ru on hxxps://x.com?
And is it ok to redirect the visitors of x.ru to hxxps://x.com for authentication, and after that, redirect back to x.ru?

thank you.

Comment: I wrote a blog entry a while back that might be helpful to you. http://www.netortech.com/Blog/Entry/12/Web-passport-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look any Google auth page it's redirect you to a SSL login page then returns to a simple http one. So i think this will be fine.

IMO you can store cookie informations in a database with a unique token then check this data against stored cookies/session variables.

Comment: Not a bad idea!  
Is this a better solution than passing all cookie informations through the URL?

Comment: I think it's definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done precisely as you want.  x.com and x.ru are different sites; if they could share cookie data, x.ru and gmail.com could also.  That would be bad.

See [Cross domain cookie access (or session)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939268/cross-domain-cookie-access-or-session) .

I believe you can set a third-party cookie for x.ru from x.com, but third-party cookies are often blocked by users' browers (for good reason).

Comment: x.ru is an addon domain, so there is only one real webshop and database. Just the language is different. I did some search for third-party cookies, and you are right, it is not the best choice.

Comment: @Tsfed : if they're really the same site, why not make them share a domain?  If you had foo.x.com and bar.x.com, you could set the cookie domain to 'x.com' and they could share.

Comment: I think it's more seo friendly to have different domains than different subdomains. Or not?

Comment: @Tsfed No, you really don't want to contort your site structure based on search engine behavior.  Bad idea.

Comment: What do you mean by contort the structure? The content and the structure would be the same an a subdomain too. Which have better value, two different subdomains or two domains?
(Canon do not use subdomains: canon.de and canon.co.uk)