# How to Set Cross Domain Cookie using Redirect?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, cross-domain, single-sign-on

everyone

I have two websites www.web1.com and www.web2.com. Now I want to write a cookie in web1 and make it write to web2 by Response.Redirect. 
If it works I want to implement a simple sso through this approach.
However, I can't read the cookie in web2. Could somebody help me to find out whether there's something wrong with my code or cookies can't be shared cross domain by this way.
thanks:)

here's the code:

in www.web1.com/Default.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie ck = new HttpCookie("userid", "00000001");

    ck.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

    ck.Domain = ".web2.com";

    Response.Cookies.Add(ck);

    Response.Redirect("http://www.web2.com/Default.aspx");
}
```

and code in www.web2.com/Default.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["userid"] != null)
    {
        lbCookie.Text = Request.Cookies["userid"].Value;
    }
    else
    {
        lbCookie.Text = "No Cookies";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the answers (especially @aleemb's answer) to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939268/cross-domain-cookie-access-or-session?rq=1

Comment: find this article`http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic`

Comment: @Jaya Prakash Rokkam, yes,I have read the article you mentioned, and what I've done here is exactly followed the method "A very basic Cross Domain SSO implementation model" in this article.However, it seems that transfer cookie by redirect didn't work in my code:(

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother setting cross-domain cookies, they will be blocked in most cases in all modern browsers.

Use pure HTTP GET with parameters and server-side encryption to do a cross-domain SSO.

For example, on page `www.web1.com/Default.aspx` you can add a hidden IFrame to some special page `www.web2.com/sso.aspx?userid=<encrypted,timestamped userid>` which in turn would set the cookie on `web2.com`.